# Smallest positive integer with 60 divisors

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to do the problem Mersenne asked in 1644. Find the smallest positive integer that has 60 divisors.

So far I have found the prime factors, 
$60=2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 5 $

I know that if you subtract unity to obtain $1 \times 1 \times 2 \times 4$ to use as the exponents $a^1 \times b^1\times c^2\times d^4$ however I do not know how to find $a,b,c,d$.

I even know the answer is $5040$ with $a=7, b=5, c=3, d=2$ but I do not know what theorems are used, why unity is subtracted and how the values are found. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: https://oeis.org/A005179

Answer (score 2):

This follows from properties of the [divisor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function). Say we have some number $n$ and we want to calculate how many divisors it has. This is the same as calculating $\sigma_0(n)$, where

$$\sigma_0(n)=\sum_{d|n}1.$$

If we write $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ as a product of primes, then one may show that we have

$$\sigma_0(n)=\prod_{i=1}^k(a_i+1).$$

You want to find the least $n$ such that $\sigma_0(n)=60$. So let's factorize 60 into primes. As you noted, this is $2\times 2\times 3\times 5$. Now it just remains for you to argue that we must have $k=4$, and $\{a_1+1,\dots,a_4+1\}=\{2,2,3,5\}$ under some ordering, then say why the choice you give in the question is minimal.

Comment: Wonderful, I assumed it was from the divisor function due to the minus of unity. (Guessing) it is minimal because they are the primes? I'm still really unsure on how to determine $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: So first argue that $k=4$. If $k$ were larger than 4, you'd have an extra something in the factorization of 60, so you'd get $a_5+1=1$, say, i.e. $a_5=0$, which means that we don't need to worry about $k$ being larger than 4. What if $k$ were 3? You'd end up with two of the $a_i+1$ being prime and one being a product of two primes, and you should be able to see that this isn't going to lead to a minimal $n$ (you'll be raising things to larger powers). If $k$ were 1 or 2, add in some extra $a_i=0$ to apply the $k=3$ argument. So you have $\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}=\{1,1,2,4\}$...

Comment: ...and if you want it to be minimal, then you'd better raise the smaller numbers to the largest powers.

Comment: There are a few more possibilities to try:  for example $2^9\cdot 3^2 \cdot 5$, but because $2^5 \gt 7$ this will be larger.